# Flex LinkBar similar to iGoogle links

Tags: apache-flex, igoogle

I wanted to create a Flex LinkBar that looks similar to the iGoogle links. The links are expandable (one level-deep) by clicking on a plus button. I've considered styling a Tree or Accordion to get the desired look and feel. But before I spend time on one approach versus another, I thought to ask first.

Does anyone know a component that I could use to achieve this? Or an example of someone doing a similar vertical navigation bar? It should only be one level deep and some parent nodes might not have children (doesn't expand).

Thanks in advance....

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to create something like this.  Just use a standard List w/ an itemRenderer that takes care of the "hiding / expanding".  I don't know of a component like this that exists, though.

Comment: IF you have specific questions, feel free to post a new questions, or to edit this one.  If you want one-on-one help; feel free to contact me directly.  Components are my thing.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with a expand/collapse list. The problem is that it should behave like a linkbar, except that some links might have child links associated to them. But doing the list approach, it was difficult to manage the selected states, the selected skin should look like iGoogle (coming out to the form).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to update with what I actually implemented. I ended up using a Tree and styled it to look and behave like a linkbar with that can have child links.